# New Data Frame Column with Conditional Value

Tags: r, plyr, apply, dplyr

I'm trying to add a new column to a data frame and keep getting errors.

Here's the `dput` for the dataframe `procs`:
https://gist.github.com/stuboo/21bd8580212ac2aa0cf3
which produces:

```
      PROCEDU1 PROCEDU2 PROCEDU3 PROCEDU4 GroupP1 GroupP2
13927     684-     7077     5979     7051       1       1
13928     685-     7051     708-     7032       1       0
13929     7052                                  1       0
```

I'm trying to add another column (TRUE/FALSE) by determining if the total of GroupP1 + GroupP2 is greater than 1.

I've tried this:

```
procs$GroupP3 <- apply(procs, 1, function(x) as.numeric(procs$GroupP1[x] + procs$GroupP2[x]) > 1)
```

and this:

```
procs$GroupP3 <- apply(procs, 1, function(x) as.numeric((procs[x,]$GroupP1 + procs[x,]$GroupP2) > 1))
```

No luck.

What I'd like to see is this:

```
      PROCEDU1 PROCEDU2 PROCEDU3 PROCEDU4 GroupP1 GroupP2 GroupP3
13927     684-     7077     5979     7051       1       1       1
13928     685-     7051     708-     7032       1       0       0
13929     7052                                  1       0       0
```

Comment: `procs$Group3 <- ifelse(procs$Group1+procs$Group2 > 1, TRUE, FALSE)`. Or if you are using `1` to represent `TRUE` and `0` for `FALSE`, `procs$Group3 <- ifelse(procs$Group1+procs$Group2 > 1, 1, 0)`.

Comment: @nrussell that is the same as `procs$Group3 <- procs$Group1+procs$Group2 > 1`

Comment: @hadley Thank you, I overlooked that.

Comment: Thank you both.  I ended up using `procs$GroupP3 <- as.numeric(procs$GroupP1+procs$GroupP2 > 1)` I clearly have a lot of learning to do, so I appreciate very much the time it took you to reply (with such a simple solution) to a problem I created by trying to make things too complex.

Comment: `with(data, { (sum(GroupP1, GroupP2) > 1)+0 })`

Answer (score 0):

This is not pretty, but it prodcued the desired result.

```
procs_count <- nrow(procs)
i <- 1
while(i<= procs_count){
  procs$GroupP3[i] <- ifelse(procs$GroupP1[i] + procs$GroupP2[i] > 1, 1, 0)
  i <- i+1
}
```